# What do "it doesn't work" and "phrase" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm confused with these two and their usages.

Comment: These two what? What is the context? What is confusing to you about their usages? What sources have you checked and what have you learned from them?

Answer (score 2):

"It doesn't work" has three prominent uses.

1. it is frequently used to mean that something mechanical or that has a function is broken and does not function.  "I dropped my smart phone and now it doesn't work."
2. it is also used to say that some claim is false.  I might claim that I am the heir to the throne of England for some reason, and someone who knows better might say that that reason doesn't work.
3. "it doesn't work" can also be used to state that a particular combination of styles or colors are incompatible.

I don't have the slightest idea why you are asking what "phrase" means.  Got a dictionary? :-)

Comment: (1) is the basic meaning, from the MACHINE WORK frame (which is itself a metaphoric extension of the HUMAN WORK frame, parallelling and accompanying its mechanical extension). (2) and (3) are metaphors; IDEAS are MACHINES, and something like ART is MACHINE CONSTRUCTION. Both are pretty silly if you look at them literally; but practically nobody ever does, even when they carry over silly ideas from one frame to another.

Comment: Cyberherbalist, I asked that question is because it has more than one meanings like many other words and some words share the same meaning. So when I say phrase, I'm not sure if listeners would know what meaning I'm referring to.